# (Jenkins) MsBuild Error - Missing Depended Reference

Tags: c#, .net, jenkins, msbuild

I'm using C# with .Net framework 4.6.1 and all projects targets to 4.6.1 too...
But I have an error from MSbuild (jenkins) when building our Mvc application. Here is the error;

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\NewPara - MvcBackend ( Admin )\Cheetah\Cheetah.Admin\Cheetah.Admin.csproj" (Rebuild target) (1) ->
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\NewPara - MvcBackend ( Admin )\Cheetah\Cheetah.HttpClientWrapper\Cheetah.HttpClientWrapper.csproj" (default target) (2:3) ->
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\NewPara - MvcBackend ( Admin )\Cheetah\Core\Cheetah.Core.Components\Cheetah.Core.Components.csproj" (default target) (3:4) ->
(CoreCompile target) -> 

  Log\Implementations\SerilogLogManagerConfigurator.cs(42,57): error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\NewPara - MvcBackend ( Admin )\Cheetah\Core\Cheetah.Core.Components\Cheetah.Core.Components.csproj]
  Log\Implementations\SerilogLogManagerConfigurator.cs(71,55): error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\NewPara - MvcBackend ( Admin )\Cheetah\Core\Cheetah.Core.Components\Cheetah.Core.Components.csproj]
```

I have added "System.Runtime" dll to neccessary projects with "Add Reference" but this time solution not building because of the another error "there is two same referance. Resolve conflicts" etc.

So did you get this error before? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You need to install reference assemblies on the build server as well as proper MSBuild version 14.0.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the full answer to your question is here: http://www.lyalin.com/2014/04/25/the-type-system-object-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-reference-mvc-pcl-issue/

Comment: One more this you need to check that on your build server installed ASP.NET MVC with a version you are using on your development machine.